# Custom Class view and selector reference

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a custom class that just has some basic functions I can reuse once the class is initialized in any viewController. The problem is I don't know how to refer to the view or any functions being called in the #selector and I get the error: use of unresolved identifier "view". Anyone know how that's done? The sample below is to create a new UIButton.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Utils {

var newUpdatesBtn: UIButton!

func setupButtonNewUpdates() {
    newUpdatesBtn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) // .System
    newUpdatesBtn.setTitle("New Updates", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    newUpdatesBtn.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 123, height: 27)
    newUpdatesBtn.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: 90) // 80 point button, 20 point status bar, 40 point half button, 8 point margins
    newUpdatesBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "new-updates"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    newUpdatesBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
    newUpdatesBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    newUpdatesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newUpdatesButtonPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.newUpdatesBtn.alpha = 0;
    self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(newUpdatesBtn)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.newUpdatesBtn.alpha = 1;
    })
}

}
```

(problem lines)

**view**.bounds.width

```
newUpdatesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newUpdatesButtonPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Do you want the ViewController to implement `newUpdatesButtonPressed` or the `Utils` class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need multiple ViewController's to implement the newUpdatesButtonPressed that's inside the Utils class. So basically just initialize and use that class method anywhere I need it.

Comment: For one, your class is simply `Utils`. Since it doesn't inherit from a view controller you don't get access to properties like `view` or `navigationController`.

Comment: Your problem is that you have created another Object class that is completely independent of any UIViewController, so of course it doesn't know anything about `view` or `navigationController`.  You could implement this as a protocol extension or you could have the view controller pass itself to this function as an argument, but really this code seems to be too tightly coupled to the view controller to be in a separate class.  You could create a similar function that merely returned a `UIButton` instance and leave it up to the UIViewController to set up the action handler and add it to the view

Comment: Since you are adding this button to a `UINavigationController`, you could be better off just subclassing `UINavigationController`

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for explaining that, I wasn't sure what my options were. I do have a UIAlertController method in Utils as well that does pass in the viewController like you said, but it's a lot simpler and not as tightly coupled. I can just put the function in each place I need it, just wanted to know kind of a best practice.

Comment: @Paulw11 I haven't done a lot of subclassing, I'll check out how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to avoid repeating code, but sticking a bunch of unrelated functions into a Utils class isn't a good solution

Comment: @Paulw11 Gotcha, that makes sense and if there are some more related ones that come up, I'll have some options now that I know about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have not set any reference in view property.
You can do like this:

```
func setupButtonNewUpdates(targetView:UIView)
{
newUpdatesBtn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) // .System
.
.
.
newUpdatesBtn.center = CGPoint(x: targetView.bounds.width / 2, y: 90) // 80 point button, 20 point status bar, 40 point half button, 8 point margins
.
.
.
targetView.addSubView(newUpdatesBtn);
}
```

Now whenever you call this method from any viewcontroller just pass the view of that VC. for example:

```
var util:Utils = new Utils();
util.setupButtonNewUpdates(self.view);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good to know how this is done exactly. And to go along with the other comments above I should probably use this in more generic cases.